# Print Posts if Custom Field Value Date equal or greater than Today Date

Tags: custom-field

I want to print posts if Custom Field Value (Expiry) formatted as 31 April 2021 is equal to or greater than today date (19 April 2021). I have tried with the below code but not working.

```
    <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th><th>Click</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
 <?php
     $today = strtotime(date('d F Y'));
        $datecf = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Expiry', true );
        $cfdate = (!empty($datecf))? strtotime($datecf) : false;
        if($today <= $cfdate){
    ?>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
          <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Check Here</a> </span> </td> </tr>
     <?php
     } 
    // Posts not found
      else {
       ?>
       <tr> 
         <td><p>There is no Active Posts Now, Check Tommorrow!</p></td>
       </tr>
     <?php
       }
        ?> 
         </tbody>
           </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example , suppose expiry date is (19 April 2021) AND also your Today Date is equal like(19 April 2021) or greater then Like Tomorrow date (20 April 2021),So You will get all the posts from today's date,
Here, date format is (dd-mm-yyyy) as defualt (19-04-2021).
But, as your requirement format ('d F Y') like this (19 April 2021).
So, as per my example you can use this format Like
**$today   = strtotime(date('d F Y'));**
But must remember that, Your posts Custon field return value As per your requirement date format.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Click</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
//  $today   = strtotime(date('d F Y'));
    $today   = date('Y-m-d');
    $args    = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'expire_date',
                'value'   => $today,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type'    => 'DATE'
            )
        )
    );
    $query   = new WP_Query($args);
    $ex_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expire_date', true);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Check Here</a></td> 
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <tr> 
                <td><p>There is no Active Posts Now, Check Tommorrow!</p></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @vishwa This works, now after implementing this on the taxonomy custom template then it returns only one post value, but that taxonomy has 3 posts that satisfy date condition but are not printed by the code, I tried `posts_per_page' => -1,` but still not works.

Comment: hello @PuneetVerma, modify this line into your code and try it. 
`'compare' => '<='` also include `posts_per_page' => -1` you will get all posts equal or greater than today Date